# Disabling interrupt with the ARM GIC (global interrupt controller)

Tags: arm

I have a specific requirement where I nee to disable my device interrupt for specific period without affecting other interrupts(code running on ARM processor). ARM document pointed that all GIC registers (related to enable, disable and clear interrupts) of ARM are Banked registers, that is there is one per CPU Interface. Banked registers accessible from the designated CPU and controls that CPU's PPI and SGI interrupts only.

What does that mean? If I disable a specific interrupt by writing to GIC register, does that get disabled only on that core or all on cores?

Comment: What processor do you use? There are many types of ARM processors and other third party products. How your "my device interrupt" is implemented in your system? Your question lacks many details of system.

Comment: There are many [ARM GIC questions on stack-overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[arm]+gic+is%3Aquestion) that maybe helpful to read.

Answer (score 2):

There are two register sets with the GIC; a banked per CPU set and the [**distribution**](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0425f/CACGBCHG.html) (also **distributor**) which is system global for the GIC.  For the link above, the `IrqEnSet0` is a per-CPU register which is banked (again) and handles the PPI and SGI interrupts to a CPU.  The `IrqEnSet1` is a list of global interrupts and these maybe disable.  The **distribution** (also **distributor**) can also target certain interrupts to a CPU.

ARM has many different names for these registers and [different versions](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0471b/Chdhjjhb.html) of the **GIC**.  The concepts are the same for all of them.  There is a set of registers that are not banked per-CPU and these control things globally including disabling the interrupts system wide.  Hopefully the reader is competent enough to find and read the specific controller documentation for their SOC.

> What does that mean? If I disable a specific interrupt by writing to GIC register, does that get disabled only on that core or all on cores?

- **PPI** - peripheral private interrupt.  For example, a per-CPU timer in SMP systems.
- **SGI** - software generated interrupt.  Also known as IPI on other systems.  This allows signaling from one CPU to another CPU. (IPI is inter-processor interrupt).

These interrupts only make sense for each and every CPU.  However, hardware like Ethernet, SPI, Video, CAN bus, i2c, ADC, etc. are usually system global.

For the **distributor** registers, usually the global interrupts have a read/write enable/disable.  The registers for the *per-CPU* are probably **read-only** in the distributor and indicate that the interrupt is present.  The other set of registers (per-CPU) are the normal mechanism to enable/disable the interrupt per-CPU.  Software should have an inter-lock (semaphore) when accessing the **distributor** as it is global to the system.  Alternatively, only an *elected* or boot CPU would use the **distributor**. The per-CPU registers are banked so a core may perform a *read-modify-write* without worrying about race conditions.

Reference: [ARM Generic Interrupt Controller - Architecture Specification](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ihi0048b/index.html), may require registration.

Comment: In order to make life extremely difficult for everyone, ARM has changed the names of the registers.  Appendix B of the *Architecture Specification* is a Rosetta stone between the different ARM documents on different versions of the GIC controllers.