# Do I need a lock when masking/unmasking Interrupts in the GIC on ARM

Tags: arm, hardware, interrupt

This question is a follow up to the answer by [artless noise](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1880339/artless-noise) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26773748/disabling-interrupt-with-the-arm-gic-global-interrupt-controller). As indicated

> For the distributor registers, usually the global interrupts have a read/write enable/disable. The registers for the per-CPU are probably read-only in the distributor and indicate that the interrupt is present. The other set of registers (per-CPU) are the normal mechanism to enable/disable the interrupt per-CPU. Software should have an inter-lock (semaphore) when accessing the distributor as it is global to the system.

Now the Architecture Specification Version 2 indicates that the `GICD_ISENABLERn` (unmasking interrupts) and the `GICD_ICENABLERn` (masking interrupts) only change states when a `1` is written, but writes of `0` are ignored. So these registers can be written without doing a read (as is currently done for example in the Linux Implementation).

```
/*
 * Routines to acknowledge, disable and enable interrupts
 */
static void gic_mask_irq(struct irq_data *d)
{
    u32 mask = 1 << (gic_irq(d) % 32);

    raw_spin_lock(&irq_controller_lock);
    gic_writel_relaxed(mask, gic_dist_base(d) +
                GIC_DIST_ENABLE_CLEAR + (gic_irq(d) / 32) * 4);
    if (gic_arch_extn.irq_mask)
        gic_arch_extn.irq_mask(d);
    raw_spin_unlock(&irq_controller_lock);
}

static void gic_unmask_irq(struct irq_data *d)
{
    u32 mask = 1 << (gic_irq(d) % 32);

    raw_spin_lock(&irq_controller_lock);
    if (gic_arch_extn.irq_unmask)
        gic_arch_extn.irq_unmask(d);
    gic_writel_relaxed(mask, gic_dist_base(d) + GIC_DIST_ENABLE_SET +
                            (gic_irq(d) / 32) * 4);
    raw_spin_unlock(&irq_controller_lock);
}
```

This code does contain locks to the configuration registers of the Distributor, but I am unsure if these are really needed (or what would happen if these are dropped).

If two cores are trying to mask different interrupts (configured by the same register) at the same time, this would cause two `1`s being written to different places at the same register. However, the interconnect should cause both writes to go through, so this would cause both interrupts to be masked (as expected).

Similarly if both cores are trying to mask the same interrupt (in that case it even does not matter if one of the writes get lost).

The only case I could see, which would mean trouble, is if one core tries to mask an interrupt while the other core simultaneously tries to unmask the same interrupt. But in that case the result would be rather unpredictable even with a lock (in case of no lock the distributor would have to "decide" somehow, in case of the lock the behavior depends on who first acquires the lock). So again the lock does not help.

Or am I maybe mistaken, that both writes from the different cores to the same word always have to go through and memory optimizations can cause one of the writes to be lost (this would have to happen within the interconnect, as no real memory is involved). Where is this specified?

Comment: The spin locks are not to protect the enable/disable bits.  The GIC hardware with set/clear registers is race free.  However, I think the `gic_arch_extn` might need them.

Comment: @artlessnoise: So if I understand correctly, they are for keeping the HW state and the data tracked by `gic_arch_extn.irq_mask(d)` etc. consistent? That would make sense then. Thank you for the help.